# How is PTRACE_SINGLESTEP implemented?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, x86-64, ptrace

To the best of my knowledge (I could be wrong), there's no way to just execute *one* instruction on an x86-64 system.  Perhaps instead you could execute the instruction followed by the 'ud2' opcode to trigger a signal -- but then you have to worry about the instruction modifying control flow and going somewhere else.

Yet, if I understand correctly, the ptrace() syscall has a SINGLESTEP option that will execute only a single instruction.  How is this implemented?  I can't imagine the kernel has some kind of disassembler to identify the instruction and reason about it.  So, is there some kind of architectural feature it's using that I don't know about?  Or something entirely different?

Comment: I not up-to-date on this, but is the Trap Flag (TF) no longer a thing?

Comment: nah, I just didn't know about it!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, there's an architectural single-step flag on x86.  Returning from kernel to user-space gives the kernel a chance to set both RIP/RFLAGS at the same time, so it can set the single-step for user-space without having it trigger on a kernel instruction.

For some reason, the [Trap Flag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trap_flag) has its own wikipedia article!  See also [wikipedia's EFLAGS article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLAGS_register).

See the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki for links to Intel's architecture manuals which document all of this.

---

> Perhaps instead you could execute the instruction followed by the 'ud2' opcode to trigger a signal

Then you'd need code to determine x86 instruction lengths, to know where to set a software breakpoint.  And you wouldn't use `ud2`, you'd use [`int3` which exists for this purpose.](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/intn:into:int3:int1)

x86 also has debug registers (dr0..7) which can set hardware breakpoints without modifying the code, or can monitor for access or write to a given data address.  (GDB `hbreak` uses those, as do GDB watchpoints on constant addresses)

But for jump/call/ret and other instructions that might have a special effect on RIP, you'd need to decode and emulate to figure out the destination to put an `int3` at the destination.  A memory-indirect jump using an addressing mode like `jmp qword [fs: rax]` would require the debugger to know the FS segment base to even know what address it will load a pointer from.  (I assume you can get this with ptrace as easily as actual register values, unlike inside the guest program itself `rdfsbase` is a new extension.)  So it's possible as long as your debugger has stopped all other threads so you can't have a TOCTOU race condition with another thread modifying the jump target pointer between reading it and continuing execution.

---

**Fun fact**: not all ISAs have hardware support for `PTRACE_SINGLESTEP`.

Case in point, the Linux kernel used to emulate it for ARM, but that required an ARM disassembler in the kernel to place a breakpoint at the next instruction, even if a branch target.  It was removed in ~2011; now `ptrace(PTRACE_SINGLESTEP)` returns `-ENOSYS` on ARM.

They just ripped out all that complexity instead of trying to make it SMP-safe and support every new instruction like Thumb-2 and so on. (http://lists.infradead.org/pipermail/linux-arm-kernel/2011-February/041324.html)

So debuggers have to manually use breakpoints on such ISAs instead of having the kernel do it for them.  If that means other threads notice a debug-break opcode in memory temporarily, that's not the kernel's problem.  (Normally debuggers like GDB *do* stop all threads while you're single-stepping.)

And it means debuggers will have to decode branch instructions to figure out where to put the breakpoint.  Including register-indirect and/or predicated branches.