# Conditions that make a tracee stopped, even though its parent didn't require it

Tags: x86, gdb, x86-64, ptrace

I am trying to learn to use ptrace, I wrote a simple assembly stub that 1/ calls ptrace(0,0,0,0) (the syscall, not the libc function). Then displays hello world then spawns a shell. I run my code from a bash shell.
Hello world is displayed, however my process is stopped before the execve(/bin/sh) (I get the bash notification of a background process)
Is it because of ptrace ? Also when issuing the "fg" command to continue execution, nothing happens and I have to close the terminal since ctrl-c doesn't work... What exactly is happening ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [execve man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html):

> If the current program is being ptraced, a SIGTRAP signal is sent to it after a successful execve().

Using `ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME)` makes your process be a tracee of its parent, so that execve SIGTRAP behaviour applies to your process even if the parent *doesn't* `PTRACE_ATTACH` or make any other ptrace system calls.  e.g. if it's a normal shell like bash rather than a debugger like GDB.  (I assume `PTRACE_TRACEME` is `0`.)

See also [How does gdb start an assembly compiled program and step one line at a time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69762022/how-does-gdb-start-an-assembly-compiled-program-and-step-one-line-at-a-time) for a more detailed walk-through of how GDB uses `ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME)` after fork but before execve, so the GDB process can trace the new process.

Comment: I assume it's not possible to handle this SIGTRAP in the tracee, in order to run normally even if the parent is not expecting to trace you ?

Comment: @AaaBbb: Probably not, I think it's delivered after the execve replaces the old process including its signal handlers and sigaction settings, and I don't think you can make ignoring SIGTRAP persist across execve.  Yeah, `sigaction` says `execve` resets signal dispositions to their defaults.  But IDK why you'd ever want to run `PTRACE_TRACEME` in a process that wasn't actively cooperating with a specific parent.  Just don't do that in the first place, except after fork, right before execve!  If you want to attach to another process, just do it with `PTRACE_ATTACH`.

Comment: I see, I simply wanted to implement an anti-debugging security technique, where if ptrace==-1 we exit else we start malware execution (in our case a shell). But I now I understand it's limited to non-sigtrap causing instructions like exec.